# Fill pdf check field with iText7

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext, itext7

I'm trying check a checkbox on my PDF with iText7.
But instead of checking only one field, it's checking all fields

What I need:

[image: img]

What I get:

[image: img]

PDF when editing:

[image: img]

I think the exported value has something to do with it.
But I don't kown what to do.

[image: img]

My code:

```cs
private static void CreatePdf(string output)
{
    using var _pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("CheckTest.pdf"), new PdfWriter(output));
    var form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(_pdfDoc, true);
    var check = form.GetField("Check");
    check.SetValue("01");
}
```

PDF: [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1shZ8z5QDsgzuVNU2QIY9wfUzpTNGNbLi/view?usp=sharing)

Someone know how to check it properly?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that whatever is generating that PDF is giving the same name to all checkboxes. Not much you can do about that, as far as I'm aware, unless you can control the generation process.

Comment: This PDF isn't generated by me. If there is no way to do about it, then I will edit de PDF and changes de fields names. The problem is that I will need to change the names every time it changes by the client.

Comment: Essentially the PDF mis-uses PDF AcroForm check boxes as radio buttons instead of using genuine PDF AcroForm radio buttons. The PDF specification does not clearly specify what a PDF viewer should do in such a case (it's mis-use after all) but the PDF form generator in question most likely has experimented and determined that in the most widely used PDF viewer, Adobe Reader, this mis-use works just as they want. Other PDF processors processing such PDFs may produce completely different results without doing anything wrong.

Comment: You may try using `check.SetValue("01", false)` instead of `check.SetValue("01")` for your check boxes - this tells iText not to generate new appearances.

Comment: Thank you @mkl! `check.SetValue("01", false)` works!

Comment: Great. I'll make that an actual answer (in contrast to the comments here) which you can mark as accepted answer.

Comment: Have you tested with the pdf the op had shared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the PDF essentially mis-uses PDF AcroForm check box fields as radio buttons instead of using genuine PDF AcroForm radio button fields.

The PDF specification does not clearly specify what a PDF viewer should do in such a case (it's mis-use after all) but the developers of the PDF form generator in question probably have experimented and determined that in the most widely used PDF viewer, Adobe Acrobat Reader, this mis-use works just as they want.

As this use is beyond specification, though, other PDF processors processing such PDFs may produce completely different results without doing anything wrong.

---

That being said, there is a way to fill the form using iText and achieve results similar to those generated by Adobe Reader.

The problem at hand is that iText by default for all form field types except actual AcroForm radio button fields generates new appearances in a way appropriate for the field type when setting the field value. In your document there are three check box field objects with the same name. Thus, they are considered a single check box with three widgets representing the same value, and so the appearances are generated as you observe.

But you can tell iText to not generate new appearances, using another `SetValue` overload accepting an additional boolean value, simply replace

```
check.SetValue("01");
```

by

```
check.SetValue("01", false);
```

Now iText makes do with the existing appearances, so only the field becomes checked that has an appearance for that `"01"` value.

Beware, only prevent iText from generating appearances in cases like this. In case of text fields, for example, not updating the appearances would cause the old appearances with the former field content to continue to be displayed even though the internal field value changed.

Answer (score 0):

A did it like this:

Dim MyPDFFormCheckBoxField As Fields.PdfFormField = myform.GetField("myCheckBox")
MyPDFFormCheckBoxField.SetCheckType(PdfFormField.TYPE_CHECK)
MyPDFFormCheckBoxField.SetValue("", If(myCheckBox.IsChecked = True, True, False))

Notice that it is the second parameter of SetValue that is setting the checkbox True or False.